# Not able to change the table column width either through CSS or HTML

Tags: html, css

I am not able to change the width of the table either through css or through HTML width property.

My Html code are as follows
:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <!--  Importing css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css">
        <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Loading Flat UI -->
        <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="feedback-ques11">
            <table id="feedback-table" class="rating-table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
                <tr id="feed-ques11" class="feed-ques" >
                    <td style="width:900px;">
                        <p>Do you suggest  </p>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:300px;">
                        <div class="outer-box" id="right-box" >
                            <span class="txt">YES</span>
                            <div class="inner-box"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I am creating two columns and i am trying to change the column width like 75% and 25% . But not able to do it.

Comment: Replace `style="width:900px;"` `width="75"` and `style="width:300px;"` `width="25"` or Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WgrAP/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/54xH3/

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to prepare live example of all html and css.

Comment: See  [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/649Gj/). Working Just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the pixels value into a percentage value within the `style` attribute.

```
<td style="width:75%;">
     <p>Do you suggest</p>
</td>
<td style="width:25%;">
     <div class="outer-box" id="right-box"> <span class="txt">YES</span>
           <div class="inner-box"></div>
     </div>
</td>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L9DR3/)**

I recommend using classes instead of inline styles for performance and re-useability, like so:

```
<style>
.first {
    width:75%;
}

.second {
    width:75%;
}
</style>

<td class="first">
     <p>Do you suggest</p>
</td>
<td class="second">
     <div class="outer-box" id="right-box"> <span class="txt">YES</span>
           <div class="inner-box"></div>
     </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Inline styles are never what anyone is after, but setting the width on the <td> will apply to the whole column.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a little more @KyleSevenoaks?

Comment: Sure, when applying styles to a DOM element, it's always best to use an external stylesheet. <td style="width:75%;"> works for a quick test/fix but shouldn't be kept in a live/production environment. Applying width to a TH element will control the width of all related TD elements in its column. Of course if you only have two tds in a table, set the width on them (on one usually works)

Comment: Yes I understand that. Although, I was answering it in the same format that the OP asked.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks - Added an example with classes as well.

Comment: A definite improvement. Hope it can help the op and others that may come across this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have given width for "feedback-ques11" class name. And width of table should not be grater than its parent control. If you will give 100% width for table's parent div then you can set width of table by style as well as by css also.